# Como hacer un Array con los "Tag Inputs" creados?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de agregar Tags a un form y que estos sirvan como "filtros" de busqueda posteriormente.

Actualmente despues de utilizar algunos frameworks de frontend logre crear el input correspondiente con el siguiente codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<form action="/tags" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label">Tags</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text"  data-role="tagsinput" ></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Ahora lo que busco es que los datos del input creen un Array para poder trabajar con ese array.

que propiedades debo agregar al "Input"?

Comment: Generalmente eso se hace con un select multiple.

Comment: En este momento, ¿Cuál es el valor de tu input cuando guardas esos datos?

Comment: un string "hello,tag2"

Answer (score 0):

primero debes agregarle el atributo id al formulario, un onsubmit para validar con una función, y al input añadirle name="lo_que_tu_quieras" para trabajarlo con php y para trabajarlo con javascript te aconsejo añadirle un atributo id="lo_que_tu_quieras", ahora bien una ves teniendo esto debes hacer mas o menos lo siguiente:

```js
// Vanilla JS
function validarFormulario() {
    const formulario = document.querySelector('#formulario');
    const expresion = /^[a-z0-9]*$/i; // simple expresion para aceptar solo caracteres a a la z y números
    let tags = document.querySelector('#tags').value;
    // usa trim() para sacarle los espacios en blanco que pueda tener al inicio y al fin del string...
    // usa split('caracater_que_divide') para dividirlos y obtener el array...
    // tags = tags.trim(); puedes hacerlo de uno por uno
    // tags = tags.split(','); puedes hacerlo de uno por uno
    tags = tags.trim().split(','); // o puedes usar las dos funciones al mismo tiempo primero el trim luego el split
    console.log('tags', tags)
    // Luego puedes recorrerlo y hacer las validaciones que quieras hacer por ejemplo usando la expresion regular de arriba
    for (const iterator of tags) {
        if (!expresion.test(iterator)) {
            console.log('no cumple validacion');
            return false; // No se envia nada al servidor...
        }
    }
    console.log('Todo es valido');
    return true; // Se envían los datos al servidor...
}

// Con jQuery
function validarFormularioJQuery() {
    const formulario = $('#formulario');
    const expresion = /^[a-z0-9]*$/i; // simple expresion para aceptar solo caracteres a a la z y números
    let tags = $('#tags').val();
    // usa trim() para sacarle los espacios en blanco que pueda tener al inicio y al fin del string...
    // usa split('caracater_que_divide') para dividirlos y obtener el array...
    // tags = tags.trim(); puedes hacerlo de uno por uno
    // tags = tags.split(','); puedes hacerlo de uno por uno
    tags = tags.trim().split(','); // o puedes usar las dos funciones al mismo tiempo primero el trim luego el split
    console.log('tags', tags)
    // Luego puedes recorrerlo y hacer las validaciones que quieras hacer por ejemplo usando la expresion regular de arriba
    for (const iterator of tags) {
        if (!expresion.test(iterator)) {
            console.log('no cumple validacion');
            formulario.trigger('reset');
            return false; // No se envia nada al servidor...
        }
    }
    console.log('Todo es valido');
    return true; // Se envían los datos al servidor...
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Formulario</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="text-center">Formulario</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="/tags" method="POST" id="formulario" onsubmit="return validarFormulario()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="tags">Tags</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" name="tags" id="tags">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Puedes probar el código aquí poniendo valores separados con , en el input y ver los resultados...